# while loop in Python3

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

This is what I have to do:

> Create a while-loop that adds 6 to the number 27, 73 times. Answer
> with the result.
>
> Write your code below and put the answer into the variable ANSWER.

And this is what I have done,

```
n = 6
while n < 73:
27 + n
n + = 1

ANSWER = n
```

Comment: Well, your indentation is wrong and you are also adding 1 to `n` for some, unknown reason...

Comment: Please read how to assing new values to python variables and read your problem again, you are doing it wrong

Comment: Hint : try with 2 variables.

Comment: @Alex OP knows that it is wrong - I edited that fluff out of the post

Comment: Don't take the downvotes too personally. You can see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and you should also describe what part of the code you provided doesn't work (like the expected output vs yours), as well as any errors that you see.

Answer (score 2):

While you literally nearly do what was requested (adding 6 to the 27 a number of times), this is not what was wanted.

What they want you to do is

> Initialize a variable with 27 and add 6 to it, 73 times.

So just do

```
value = 27
i = 0
while i < 73:
    value += 6
    i += 1
ANSWER = value
```

Comment: I believe the exercise is trying to use while-loops, though

Comment: @cricket_007 You are completely right, I didn't see this.

Comment: Slight optimization: `ANSWER = 27`

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh right! :-) But they want me to put the answer into the variable `ANSWER` at the end (although, it doesn't make any real difference…)